# Ошибка при удалении текста с инпута

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Суть проблемы: При первом клике могу удалить один символ , а при последующих не получается это сделать . Подскажите в чём ошибка ?

Вот код скрипта :

```
$( "#del" ).click(function() {

var str = document.getElementById('phone').value;
document.getElementById('phone').value = str.substring(0, str.length-1);  


});
```

вот скрипт весь полностью  http://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/103/

Comment: Текст ошибки какой у вас в консоли?

Comment: @Visman в том и проблема , что в консоле нет ошибок . Но так как в скрипте я ошибок вроде не нашёл то скорее всего ошибка не в синтаксисе а в логике. Но мне не хватает ума это проверить . Выше я проложыл пример с кодом где можно взлянуть что удаляет 1 символ причем, если поле заполнено и удаляет только последний символ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В действительности, когда вы первый раз удаляете символ, он заменяется символом маски после удаления. При следующем срабатывании скрипта уже удаляется символ маски и на его место снова устанавливается символ маски. И так до бесконечности. То есть вам надо переписать этот скрипт так, чтобы он удалял последнюю цифру, а не последний символ в поле ввода.